# I/O value error: Operation on closed file

Tags: io, operation

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to make the program read an excel file and then create a new file with a similar name and write the excel row to that file.

The error occurs at "for row in excelreader:"

Here's my code:

```
import os
import csv
dirlist=os.listdir("//GOLLUM/tbg2/tbg2/forritGB")
print dirlist
for filename in dirlist:
   if ".csv" in filename:
       with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
           excelreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
       file=open("xml_"+dir, 'w+')
       for row in excelreader:
           file.write(row)
   else:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the file after the `for row in excelreader:` loop